# Generate X509 certificate or RSA key with known p and q primes

Tags: openssl, rsa

my problem seems to be easy but I was not able to solve it...
Do you know how generate a X509 certificate (using ssl) or a RSA key with fixed primes ? I only find key generator but not calculators with parameters.

Hope i'm clear,

thanks a lot

Comment: The certificate only contains the public key, which for RSA is the product of the primes and encrypt exponent.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate a new `RSA` structure and set its relevant members directly, then call `RSA_check_key()` to ensure you didn't mess something up. Afterwards, do whatever you need to with your new key.

It's not clear why you would ever want to do this, but it's not impossible.